# Round Time up to the nearest minute…

Tags: c#

Is there a simple method to round up DateTime to the nearest minute? i.e.. 2011-08-11 16:58:20 becomes 2011-08-11 16:59:00

I have already tried several solutions

```
dt.AddMinutes((60 - dt.Minute) % 10);
```

but that seems to add 1 whole minute.

Comment: I think you meant `dt.AddSeconds(60 - dt.Second);`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos OP wants to round up.

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov That adds a minute if the `DateTime` is already on an exact minute.

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov `dt.AddSeconds(dt.Second == 0 ? 0 : 60 - dt.Second)`

Comment: @ValerijDobler That's going to give some wildly incorrect answers.

Comment: Rounding should base on the Ticks property not Second. Otherwise rounded DateTime still have different values for milliseconds.

Comment: `new DateTime((dt.Ticks + 600000000 - 1) / 600000000 * 600000000, dt.Kind)`

Comment: ^^ I'd recommend to not using a magic number, though. There are `TimeSpan.TicksPerXXX` (where XXX = Hour|Minute|Second|Millisecond) for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ChristofWollenhaupt mentioned in comments section

> Rounding should base on the Ticks property not Second. Otherwise
> rounded DateTime still have different values for milliseconds

If that's the case then create new `DateTime` and make correction to minutes based on ticks.

```
TimeSpan timeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, dt.Second, dt.Millisecond);
DateTime roundedDateTime = new DateTime(
    dt.Year,
    dt.Month,
    dt.Day,
    dt.Hour,
    dt.Minute,
    0,        //Second
    0,        //Millisecond
    dt.Kind
    );
roundedDateTime.AddMinutes(timeSpan.Ticks > 0 ? 1 : 0);
```

Comment: You say "do not add" and then do an add?

Comment: @DotNetDeveloper Why not add or subtract?

Comment: OP doesn't add/subtract from the current DateTime though.

Comment: ^^ _"**Returns a new DateTime** that adds the specified number of minutes to the value of this instance."_ - [DateTime.AddMinutes(Double) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.addminutes?view=net-6.0)

Comment: As the dupe's answers and @ChristofWollenhaupt in comments above say: it's better (i.e. more correct) to round based on Ticks.

Comment: @DotNetDeveloper This looks better, but we still have the issue with Ticks with your answer based on the unclear question of the OP. What if, the original DateTime was 2011-08-11 16:58:20.999. Your code rounds this down to 2011-08-11 16:58:20.